# Using RoundhousE with dll File

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, dll, roundhouse

I've decided to use RoundhousE for my database. Now there are three ways to use this tool. With MSBuild, a DLL File or the console application. I found some documentations how to use the MSBuild variant and I know how to use the console application but I can not find anything how to use the DLL in Visual Studio and how to call/configure RoundhousE this way.

Does someone know where to find a detailled documentation or could someone explain me this?

Comment: @jainishkapadia don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms. That doesn't increase readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DLL is used in a few places, like with DropkicK - it may not be a bad idea to explore how it uses it, as there is not much documentation with this otherwise. You can also review how Roundhouse RefreshDatabase uses it as well.

- DropkicK - https://github.com/chucknorris/dropkick/blob/master/product/dropkick/Tasks/RoundhousE/RoundhousEClientApi.cs
- RoundhousE-EntityFramework RefreshDatabase - https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse-entityframework

HTH